# Visual Studio C# intellisense not using edited XML file

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I have annotated my C# code with  descriptors of my variables, functions etc.

```
<summary>This is a variable</summary>
double v;
```

If I then build my project, navigate to the XML file, and edit it by hand Visual Studio does not recognise the changes I have made.

```
<member name="P:MyProject.v">
<summary>I HAVE BEEN EDITED</summary>
</member>
```

However, if I create a new project, and reference the original one, then the new project uses the hand-edited XML.

Does VisualStudio not use the generated XML for an active project? Is there a way I can force it to?